# Parse XML using XDocument in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows-phone-8, linq-to-xml

Can any one tell me how to parse XML which is in this format using XDocument in Windows phone 8

```
 <search total=""  totalpages="">
 <domain>
 <makes filter="">
 <make cnt="374" image="abc.png">One</make>
 <make cnt="588" image="bca">Two</make>
 <make cnt="105" image="tley.png">Three</make>
 <make cnt="458" image="mw.png">Four</make>
 </makes>
 </domain>
 </search>
```

Right now i am using this code but unable to get the data out. I need image and name from this XML.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(flickRes);
var rootCategory = xdoc.Root.Elements("makes");
List<string> list = new List<string>();

foreach (XElement book in rootCategory.Elements("make"))
{
    string id = (string)book.Attribute("image");
    string name = (string)book;
    Debug.WriteLine(id);
    //list.Add(data);
}
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Elements` returns only direct children of current element (with matching name, when provided). Because `<makes>` is not direct child of root element, `xdoc.Root.Elements("makes")` will return empty collection.

Add another `Element("domain")` call on `xdoc.Root` before calling `Element("makes")`.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(flickRes);
var rootCategory = xdoc.Root.Element("domain").Element("makes");
List<string> list = new List<string>();

foreach (XElement book in rootCategory.Elements("make"))
{
    string id = (string)book.Attribute("image");
    string name = (string)book;
    Debug.WriteLine(id);
    //list.Add(data);
}
```