# Read data from XML file in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8.1

guys! I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 application and I want to read some content from a XML file. I know how to read data from a structure like this

```
<strings>
    <string01>Some text.</string01>
    <string02>Another text.</string02>
</strings>
```

declaring a class with strings

```
public class TextStrings {
    public string string01 { get; set; }
    public string string02 { get; set; }
}
```

and using XmlSerializer like this

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TextStrings), new XmlRootAttribute("strings"));
string filename = "TextData.xml";
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///" + filename));
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync());
object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
TextStrings xmlData = (TextStrings)obj;
```

and then I insert text into a TextBlock writing

```
txtBlock.Text = xmlData.string01;
```

Now I pick up a XML file with this structure

```
<header>
    <book name="Book 01" chapters="10">
        <chapter n="1">
            <verse n="1">Some text.</verse>
            <verse n="2">More text.</verse>
            ...
        </chapter>
        ...
    </book>
    ...
</header>
```

So, for example, I want to insert verse 2 of chapter 1 of Book 01 in a TextBlock. How can I do this using XmlSerializer as before? Or is there another way? Because tags are the same and have these attributes - "n", "book", "chapters".

Can you write some code? As I'm still learning all this stuff, it's hard to understand without looking at the code itself. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML using XDocument in Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745665/parse-xml-using-xdocument-in-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(XDocument.Load("XMLFile.xml").ToString());
IXmlNode mynode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/header/book[@name='Book 01']/chapter[@n='1']/verse[@n='2']");
string mytext = mynode.InnerText;
MyTextBlock.Text = mytext;
```

Works perfectly!